# How can I change (MSBuildExtensionPath) in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

In VS2022, I start a new Xamarin Android App project and decided I needed to add a nuget package ([step one here, but not really relevant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases). The add package command returns the following error:

```
C:\Users\user\Source\Repos\user\project\project.csproj(112,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

Line 112 of project.csproj is:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" />
```

That is from the template in VS2022 with nothing changed. Now, I found where I have that targets file, but it's not in the above location. So, whatever this MSBuildExtensionsPath is, I'd like to change it so this can work correctly. However, I cannot find information on how to do this in any documentation.

I figure I could remove the MSBuildExtensionPath and manually set the directory, but that would limit me to using this device to work on the project, and force me to make that override and have that limitation in every other project I wanted to do this on.

### Edit

Some follow up stuff I did this evening:

I tried using the cmd prompt to set MSBuildExtensionPath [as in this distantly similar old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876824/overriding-msbuildextensionspath-in-the-msbuild-task-is-flaky).

I also attempted to look through the registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild but there were no keys for ExtensionsPath in any of the subfolders.

I'm quite new to programming.

Comment: Can you share the complete .csproj file? I try to add nuget package in Xamarin Android App project but can't reproduce this issue. Is it useful to copy the file C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin to C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100?

Comment: I copied the entire Xamarin folder under Visual Studio to the appropriate place it was trying to go in dotnet\sdk\7.0.100 and that seems to have picked it up. I didn't expect this to be a reproducible problem but that makes it only more baffling. I could share the .csproj file but it really was just the unmodified result of New -> Project -> Android App -> Tabbed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You said "The add package command returns the following error", what command did you use? Did you try to repair vs in visual studio installer?

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any others questions.

Answer (score 0):

I used this command `dotnet add package sqlite-net-pcl --version 1.8.116`
to reproduce the problem:
[image]

[.NET Core and its command-line interface (CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new#arguments) may not compatible with Xamarin

You can use `NuGet\Install-Package sqlite-net-pcl -Version 1.8.116` in Package Manager Console to install the package.